# nothing collection in for each loop - how to handle it?

Tags: vb.net

How do I handle a for each loop when the collection is nothing, I thought it would just skip over but i get an exeption?

Do I need to wrap the foreach loop in a if to check for nothing and only if it is not nothing then enter in the for each loop?

```
For Each item As String In MyStringList 

    'do something with each item but something myStringList will be nothing?


Next
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with C# - removing tag.

Comment: The answer to your second question is, yes.

Comment: @JoshE I disagree, `foreach` exists in C#, and fetching an iterator from a null `IEnumerable` instance performs the same in either language.  Nothing VB-specific except the demonstration code.

Comment: the OP didn't provide any context to indicate that C# was part of the discussion. C# and VB have different syntactical elements, e.g. `Nothing` exists in VB and not C# even if there are elements that behave in similar (not necessarily equivalent) fashions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I need to wrap the foreach loop in a if to check for nothing and only if it is not nothing then enter in the for each loop?

Yes.

```
If MyStringList IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each item As String In MyStringList 
       'do something ...
    Next
End If
```

[Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93497/foreach-should-check-for-null) says it is by design:

> I think that most foreach loops are written with the intent of
>   iterating a non-null collection. If you try iterating through null you
>   should get your exception, so that you can fix your code. Foreach is
>   basically a syntactic convenience. As such, it should not be "magical"
>   and do unexpected things under the hood. I agree with the post that
>   proposed the use of empty collections rather than null. (They can
>   typically be reused quite a bit using singleton techniques).

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use [the patented](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/05/02/22/1310232/microsofts-isnot-patent-continued) `IsNot` operator instead?

Comment: @vcsjones: That's a matter of taste. But yes, that's also possible. I've started VB.NET with 1.1, so i'm using `Not ... Is`.

Comment: I was mostly just being snarky about "the patented" part.

Comment: This link 404s, needs updating

Answer (score 4):

Adding the `If collection IsNot Nothing Then` is not that onerous, but if you do have this construct a lot, this Extension method may be preferable:

```
    '''---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' Extension Function: OrEmpty
    ''' 
    ''' <summary>
    '''   Returns an empty enumeration if the source is Nothing.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' 
    ''' <typeparam name="T">The type to create an enumeration of. Normally inferred.</typeparam>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="Source">The source enumeration.</param>
    ''' 
    ''' <returns>The source enumeration unless it is Nothing; then an empty enumeration.</returns>
    ''' 
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' </remarks>
    ''' 
    ''' <revisionhistory>
    '''   100930 MEH Created.
    ''' </revisionhistory>
    '''---------------------------------------------------------------------
    <Extension()> _
    Function OrEmpty(Of T)(ByVal Source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        If Source IsNot Nothing Then _
            Return Source
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of T)()
    End Function
```

And with `Option Infer On` you don't need to specify the type, so the example use is just:

```
For Each item As String In MyStringList.OrEmpty 

    'do something with each item but something myStringList will be nothing?

Next
```

Comment: Kudos... simplified a tad: `Return If(Source, Enumerable.Empty(Of T)())`

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to wrap the foreach loop in a if to check for nothing and
>   only if it is not nothing then enter in the for each loop?

Yeap, that's what you have to do. Or ensure that the function that returns the string list (if you have control over it) never returns a null array but an empty collection instead which by the way is the standard approach for functions returning collections - they should never be null as it makes them LINQ unfriendly and forces you to write ifs everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not IsNothing(collection)
' For Each goes here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the  [if(arg1, arg2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) operator.

```
For Each item As String In If(MyStringList, Enumerable.Empty(Of String))
    'do something .....
Next
```

The If operator will return the second argument, the empty list, if the first argument is nothing

The For Each ... Next statement will evaluate the If operator only once before the loop starts ([Technical Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement#technical-implementation))

To improve readability, a more explicit implementation is to define the group/collection before the For Each ... Next statement.

```
Dim myListThatAlwaysExists as IEnumerable(of String) = If(MyStringList, Enumerable.Empty(Of String))
For Each item as String in myListThatAlwaysExists
   'do something ....
Next
```

Comment: The `If` must be analyzed on each loop. This is an undesirable side effect of your method. Never use a calculation as your enumerable, for this reason.

Comment: I was thinking of the `If` itself, not the collection returned. Maybe the compiler is smart enough to optimize that out.