# How to handle nothing in a foreach loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I have the following function:

```
 Public Sub performautowebrowserOperations()
    Try
        For Each link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") 'sometimes throws a null reference exception
            If link.GetAttribute("value") IsNot Nothing Then
                If link.GetAttribute("value") = "Compare prices" Then
                    link.InvokeMember("click")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Sometimes the commented line throws a NullReferenceException. Why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11547008/256431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the `GetElementsByTagName` so that it is outside of the For Each statement that way it will be easier to check if the Collection is Null or Empty.

```
Public Sub performautowebrowserOperations()
    Try
        Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If Not IsNothing(elements) And elements.Count > 0 Then
            For Each link As HtmlElement In elements
                If link.GetAttribute("value") IsNot Nothing Then
                    If link.GetAttribute("value") = "Compare prices" Then
                        link.InvokeMember("click")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```